# Duplicate question + duplicate question = new question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I see two compound questions that are only loosely connected to each other. Each one is trivial and can be found with Google, and can also be found on SO and is a clear duplicate. And the combination of the two separate answers leads trivially to an answer for the compound question.

For example: "How do I redirect a user to a different page after sending an email? (PHP)"

(Answer: send_email(); do_redirect();   ;)

It can be decomposed into:

- how do I send an email in PHP? (The OP may or may not already have solved this problem)
- how do I redirect the user to a different page?
- how do I execute one action after another action?

All three are not good questions, but combine them together and voila, you have a new question ;) When I see such things I just downvote, but I don't flag it in any way, because I don't find a close reason that feels right. (It's not just me; these kind of questions get downvoted a lot!)

Furthermore, decomposing a problem into parts and assembling the parts together is the essence of programming, so I just cannot understand how a programmer could even ask such a question. To me, it's like asking "How do I set the background color of button1 to red while at the same time setting the title of button2 to 'cancel'?" They are just two questions, not connected to each other, but I cannot find a duplicate for the combined question, and no other close reasons apply. (This example may be a good question if the OP were able to solve each sub-problem individually, but when combining both into the same application: problems appear and it does not work anymore.)

By combining two unrelated problems, you can avoid having your question closed as a duplicate, and you may also be able to avoid having it closed as "too broad" or as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem", but **I have the feeling that this is just a loophole.**

I understand that the OPs don't do this on purpose just to have their questions accepted; to me it seems that they just lack the analytical skills to decompose the problem into parts and search for solutions of each part separately. ("how to send email in PHP" is easy to figure out, "how to do a page redirect in PHP" is also easy. But there may not be any description on the Internet that just combines these two things, because the combination itself is trivial.)

What should be done in these cases? Just downvote? Or flag them?

(Note that as a <3k user I don't have the "custom off-topic close reason" available, but maybe that would be the answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure how you come to the conclusion that this could be used to avoid the "too broad" close reason. If the question is essentially 2 unrelated questions combined (as in your decomposition) it is likely a good candidate to be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @OGHaza good point. However, sometimes the asker is only concerned about the second question, and the first part is only there to make the question look more specific. E.g. asking "how do I redirect to another page AFTER I sent an email" is more specific than just "how do I redirect to another page". That was my idea when I wrote my post.

Comment: Re *"they just lack the analytical skills to decompose the problem into parts"*: Or they just want somebody to do the work for them. If a group of reputation points-intoxicated people are willing to do it for free, why not?

Answer (score 6):

> By combining two unrelated problems, you can avoid having your question closed as a duplicate, and you may also be able to avoid having it closed as "too broad" or as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem", but I have the feeling that this is just a loophole.

There is no loophole here; **such questions almost certainly still Need More Focus** (in the jargon of the time when this was posted, "are Too Broad").

If it appears that OP actually only needs to ask about one step, the question can be a duplicate of a question about that step. Otherwise, it should be edited or closed pending a minimal reproducible example (emphasis on *minimal*).

If OP is asking about multiple steps and they are all duplicates, gold-badge holders may find it expeditious to close with all applicable canonicals. When doing so, [it's a good idea to make a mental note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422800/523612) in case a **pattern** emerges of people trying to combine the **same** two steps; if there's an at-all reasonable way to phrase the combination so that it doesn't **sound like** separate tasks, that can become a new canonical.

Comment: Also gold badgers can close a question as duplicate of several questions. If a post asks 2 questions at once and they are both FAQ, you can dupe hammer with one target, then edit the duplicate list and add a second duplicate target. When doing something like that, make sure to leave a comment though, explaining that the different issues are answered by different duplicates.

Comment: Yes; that's what I meant with the "may find it expeditious to close with all applicable canonicals" part.

Answer (score 3):

I think, we're talking about questions where the sub-questions of it all have duplicates already.

### Hacky solution

Go to the appropriate chat room (e.g. language tag) and ask if someone may assist you in closing questions. You can only flag/vote to close with one duplicate. If someone helps you, the question may be closed with all sub-questions linked as duplicates. Reviewers still have to agree.

*Although, this streches the semantics of duplicate and should never be used.*

### Ask for clarification and possibly move on

Write a comment with links to the duplicate sub-questions. If the OP reacts by saying that they are unable to combine the solutions then you have yourself a new question. But you should watch out not to drift into help vampire territory.

Comment: Do not only ask for clarification, also VTC as "too broad".