# Closing a question as a duplicate of 5 other questions that were all answered by the closing user

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, dupehammer

Today, I answered a question which later got closed by a user with the Gold Badge, as a duplicate of 5 other questions, which were **all** answered by that close-voting user.

While I understand not every question in the list of duplicates might necessarily themselves be **exact duplicates** of the 4 others, I am wondering whether this is expected behavior.

In other words: It is OK for *User A* to answer (multiple) questions, not caring whether a duplicate already exists, then close a similar one that was answered by *User B*, and mark it as a duplicate of all those that were answered by themselves (*User A*)?

Comment: NB: I intentionally didn't provide a link to that specific question as I think it's more of a general question and I am sure anyone can easily find it if needed. And in case you get there and wonder why I also close-voted it, I initially close-voted too (for another reason) but forgot to remove my vote before answering, and my vote is now stuck.

Comment: If a user is closing a question as duplicates of several others, but they have answered *all* of those other questions, that does have a "smell" to it. Sometimes, however, I might close a question as a duplicate of a couple of questions, as the combination of the 2 answer the question, and I *might* have answered both but then the 2 duplicates aren't duplicate of each other.

Comment: I would argue (though I am not an SME) that these answers by the user are "the same": [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32615314/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31712121/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088046/2029983)

Comment: As a note, if you don't think it is a duplicate, I would argue that if the OP needs to say 5  different(?) questions make a single duplicate, then you should be using a reopen vote on the question. If you think that the question *is* a duplicate, then the only problem I would suggest there is is that the OP seems to be (or has) posted multiple duplicates in the past (such as I highlight above) and maybe those questions should also be closed as duplicates of a whatever the conanical duplicate is.

Comment: @Larnu yes, that's agreed, not every Q/A that is marked as a duplicate is necessarily a duplicate of the others (I mentioned this in my question).

Comment: @Larnu, I do agree it can be closed as a duplicate, even though I believe my answer was a bit more detailed than the listed duplicates. What I am questionning is the user behavior. Sounds a bit like, it's all fine when *I* answer them, not when someone else does.

Comment: This is why I mentioned that perhaps all/some of those duplicates should also be closed as a duplicate of what ever the conanical duplicate is; as it seems that there's *at least* 6 questions on the topic.

Comment: I often close questions as a duplicate of a self-answered question answered by myself, since I made those Q&As because these questions were asked over and over again while no good canonical answer existed. And I assume others frequently do the same, and might link multiple if the question is multi-barrelled.

Comment: And I bet that you've marked that answer as a Community Wiki answer too, @ErikA .

Comment: @ErikA that sounds like a different case than what I depicted here. Closing a question as a duplicate of another question that I answered myself is totally ok (I think). Answering several identical questions then closing one that was answered by someone else as a dupe of all the dupes I myself answered sounds like something different and questionnable (IMO).

Comment: The time between those answers is quite large though, @MrUpsidown . The 3 I linked about were answered in 2015, 2015 and 2013 respectively, and the other 2 sugggest duplicates were in 2013 and 2014. I'm not saying that makes it "ok" to answer the same question(s) over and over again with the same answer(s) but one example doesn't infer malice (though they did get [google-maps] back in 2014, so could have closed a few of those as dupes unilaterally back then). What you actually need to prove here is that this user *consistently* does this.

Comment: @Larnu, again, my goal is not to get that specific user blamed for their behavior. I wanted to learn whether it was acceptable or not. That said, I frequently stumbble upon answers by high-rep users that, to me, have a smell of *let's answer anyway, even though I know it was already answered*. Example, (by the same user, sorry) could be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263272/i-need-help-making-my-googlemaps-addlistener-to-work-for-a-marker-array) where the duplicate was even mentioned in their answer... the goal, I believe, is just to earn more reputation, no matter how.

Comment: @MrUpsidown In that case just vote to close as the suited duplicate. Answering a question should be the **last possible option**. The same as asking a new question. Most certainly it was asked in the past. You just have to find the right dupe. And if no clear dupe exists. Edit the one you think would be the best canonical and then redirect the other questions to *that*.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „exact duplicate” here? This seems to strongly affect the meaning of having answered them all. If they are duplicates, that means they should have been closed as such - and thus not answered.  If they are not duplicates, well, what’s the matter then? The formulation „not caring whether a duplicate already exists“ seems to imply they are duplicates, so why say they may not be?

Comment: My thoughts -- it depends. I user A is one of those handful of users that has likely authored a large percentage of questions on whatever site it is (there are a handful of those users on every site) -- then that's not uncommon at all -- so long as the referenced dupe is a true or close dupe. If the referenced questions are not exact or close dupes, then that is a problem and smells like the user driving traffic to his answers trolling for rep. Those are the two-ends to a continuum. If you feel it falls to the latter, flag it and have somebody look.

Comment: I've come across this a few times from a certain gold-star user and it always "feels wrong" - like using the gold star for self-promotion or rep farming. Especially when all the dupes they pick are old, low-vote answers and they omit more recent, highly voted canonical posts. Would be nice for "regular users" to have a mechanism for adding duplicates to the list provided by a gold-star.

Comment: @TylerV my opinion is that the community needs to do a better job of understanding and nominating canonical pages.  Post age is only a factor when there is a tie in comparing higher priority criteria such as: 1. Is the potential canonical question clear (and ideally include a crystal clear [mcve]) and easy to search for? Does the potential canonical page contain the most comprehensive and educational answers with VERY few bad/misleading/divergent/incorrect/code-only/redundant answers? Our goal is to provide the very best Researcher eXperience; anything else is counter to the SE mission.

Comment: @Larnu: Well, you don't get 156k reputation by closing dupes and not answering. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's a difference, however, in answering duplicate questions with catered answers and answering duplicate questions with the same answer (which the user in question seems to have done here), @EricDuminil . Don't get me wrong, there are certainly users out there that have no idea what the VTC (as duplicate) feature is and some of those are very high reputation users, however, you certainly can get 156k reputation while still adhering to the expectations of closing questions (as duplicates). It might take *longer* but that doesn't make it unachievable.

Comment: @Larnu: Yes, I totally agree. I simply forgot the \sarcasm tag. And apparently, to escape an arm in the shrug emoticon.

Comment: Are the other questions themselves duplicates of each other? Or are they addressing different facets of an unfocused or confused question?

Comment: I get the implication here. It *looks like* the gold badger likes to answer as much as possible, but in this case because someone else already answered they decided to dupe close instead. It *looks like* someone wants to direct all credit to themselves, right? But we don't have proof that this is the case, we can only suspect. And boy do we like to see patterns in things!

Comment: @Gimby, you seem to have understood my point. Patterns... maybe like [this chain of events](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72876617/timeline) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74111336/timeline) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73644078/timeline)? Always the same pattern : Place an answer then close as duplicate. Note that each time, the answer is accepted... Another option is to *list the duplicates* [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73680855/1238965) (but still place an answer).

Comment: Yeah posting an answer and then dupe closing that is a pretty unmistakable pattern.

Comment: @MrUpsidown That *specific* behaviour seems quite different from the *general* behaviour you describe in your meta question. Perhaps you want to ask a separate meta question about that different behaviour?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right, that's a different topic now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not particularly unusual, although ideally it isn't common, either. A question can be closed as a duplicate of several targets if it is complex or asks multiple things that are each solved by the different targets, respectively. *Usually* posts that ask multiple questions should be closed as Needs Focus instead of as a duplicate of something that only partially answers it.

There is a chance that some of the targets are themselves duplicates of each other, in which case it would be better to close them as dupes of one canonical instead and just use the canonical as the target. However, subject matter knowledge (or sometimes even expertise) is usually required to know whether the series of questions are duplicates of one another or not.

Regarding the fact that the targets were all answered by the subject matter expert (SME), this isn't a cause of concern *in itself*; in fact it stands to reason that as a frequent answerer and an SME in the topic/tag/language, the SME would be likely to have many answers they can draw from as good targets.

Comment: While i agree with what your saying the comment history on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined/18088046#18088046 (link from @Larnu) sort of says this was not the case, the SME deliberately left a question open after they had answered it because within 3 mins of answering put a comment saying it was a possible duplicate, the SME should have closed it or if they could not at the time vote to close it but it's still open now seems very sus

Comment: @Barkermn01 I'm not sure what your comment is referring to with "this was not the case"; I didn't prescribe any motivation for a specific closure, or even discuss a specific closure, at all.

Comment: @Barkermn01 it is significantly easier and faster to answer a question than find a duplicate. So as result if one has small amount of time there are two options - post an answer or downvote and move on. While I don't have anything against the later one, people tend to complain way more about that compared to answering and closing as duplicate later when you have time to search for duplicate (which may be 3 minutes later)...

Comment: @Barkermn01 also don't forget that without gold badge (which I think started after 2013) closure often  doesn't happen... so the "possible duplicate" comment would be the only the only (non-permanent) indication where to find answer.

Answer (score 26):

I few points that I'd like to share on this topic.

1. I regularly quintuple-hammer duplicate questions.

   - There isn't a more generous way to provide feedback to a closable question than to offer multiple pages that offer resolving advice.
   - Multi-dupe closing signals that perhaps the asker should have searched a bit longer before answering.
   - Multi-dupe closing pre-emptively refutes proposals to reopen the page.
   - Multi-dupe closing indicates that the new question is likely to be an unneeded sign post since so many duplicates are available -- therefore, it can be safely deleted.
   - I personally don't have any problem with closing a page that asks two basic questions with two atomic canonicals -- such as "how to filter an array, then reindex the results".  We don't want to create a loophole in the closure argument whereby askers know they can circumvent closure by asking increasingly complex, multifaceted questions.
   - I understand that piling on duplicates prevents the auto-redirect feature of this network, but I do not value that feature more than creating more connectivity between many posts.
   - If I hammer a page closed with 5 pages that all have an answer from me, then I would NEVER be insulted if someone else came along and curated/consolidated that cluster of dupes.  Sometimes I do not have the time/energy/focus to do the highly-demanding job of selecting a new canonical dupe target and closing many sign post pages.
2. Usually when I multi-dupe hammer a question, I am using pages that I found via Google search results.  Since Google's algorithm is tailoring my results based on what it knows about my past searches, there is a strong chance that *my* results include pages that I've visited several times before (my own).  Other times, I know that I've resolved a particular task before and I know of specific keywords in my posts.  This means I can use Stack Overflow's search function for specific keywords and tags with `user:me`.
3. Because I became woke to the importance of closing AFTER posting a thousand answers, I have posted answers to the same question asked by different users.  In recent times, I am closing pages that I answered years ago.  Also, while necro-posting, I can't always be sure which historical page the community might eventually consider to be the ultimate canonical.  When I am not confident which is best, I might post a tailored answer to multiple (old) pages.  Again, I am fine with another SME to come along and *do something* with the related pages.
4. Most importantly, I think it is important that Stack Overflow and its contributors start seeing redundant content for what it is -- a mess that needs to be tended to.  I strongly endorse the idea of "heaping content" so that SMEs have an easier time curating and relating content for the benefit of researchers. See what I mean about heaping & relating content: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418239/2943403) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417663/2943403).

In summary, there is nothing wrong with using 5 dupe targets where you posted an answer.  If those targets are indeed duplicates of each other, then I hope that a caring and responsible user will assess the related pages and close appropriately so that researchers and contributors have a better experience.  If the hammerer was trying to game the system for personal gain, it would be a bad strategy -- they are drawing attention to the fact that redundant content is not yet consolidated.

Comment: again I agree with everything you saying but I'm curious if you would say something about the comment I put on TylerH's answer, where this is not a decent amount of time but 3 mins between answers and then commenting it's a dup of the other answers they could have at that point closed it but did not

Comment: @Bar that particular set of events, IMO, stinks.  If I found _any_ dupe (posted by myself or anyone else) within 3 minutes of posting the only answer on the new page, then there is no compelling reason keeping the new answer alive. Well, actually, without a hammer and with so many FGITW posters, it was probable that another answer would have come before the closure. That said, the early years of SO are rife with bad posting practices.  We cannot turn back time, but we can take steps to clean up old messes.  This is one of those messes that is suitably addressed by closing the question.

Comment: While the two questions seems to be slightly varied in their problem, the resolving advice appears to be the same.  This highlights a relatively new perspective that curators are applying.  The perspective requires the awareness of what a good "sign post" is on Stack Overflow.  If you are using the archaic/strict interpretation of what a "duplicate question" is, then you might argue that they are not exact duplicates. If you believe that good sign posts point different questions/scenarios to a common resolving page, then the closure is appropriate -- I am in the latter camp.

Comment: I would agree, especially because those var's can change a lot because they are created by the minifier Google is using, that's why we have to use the methods :D don't want the same answer for every version Google release since a new release is auto deployed

Comment: „Again, I am fine with another SME to come along and do something with the related pages.“ It’s refreshing to see such a practical standpoint instead of black and white categories of good and bad. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I somewhat frequently do the same thing in my own areas of expertise on SO (assembly, stdatomic / memory order, etc.), and my list of reasons is almost exactly the same as yours.  100% agree with all of this answer.  And yeah, often I've written answers to many of the questions I link, since until recently few other people have been writing many in-depth answers that try to cover the territory surrounding the specific problem.

Comment: I often try to find at least one answer from someone else to include in the dup list to avoid the appearance of self-promotion, if there is one. (And give a different perspective and writing style, in case mine doesn't work for some readers). But often I think my answers are the most useful, that's why I wrote them in the first place even though there were some mostly-code answers to existing questions. Or I sometimes remember having written an answer and search it, and/or the terminology I use when searching matches what *I'd* put in an answer, but not everyone else would use the same words

Comment: Here's a fresh example of a 5x-hammer: [Counting occurance of an element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74618354/2943403)  Is this an under-researched question? I am certain that it is.  Would the asker have even posted the question if they saw any of these pages? I think not.  Does the canonical have enough signposts?  Hell, the signposts have signposts -- it's a giant mess.  This is where we could use [a team of curators to carefully consolidate content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384174/352329)

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a response to mickmackusa's answer, prompted by some chat room discussion.

There are two separate cases to consider:

### When the duplicates are substantively the same

I generally oppose using multiple (up to the system limit of 5) existing questions, all of which are essentially the same, to close as a duplicate.

- **Quantity != quality**. I used to be a strong proponent of the idea that sometimes beginners need to hear the same idea explained multiple times in order to "get it", and that one of those explanations will just "click" unpredictably. However, with more experience, I have found that *most of the time*, the problem is simply that most crowd-sourced explanations are just not that good. While repetition does help, re-reading a quality explanation is usually better than seeking alternate explanations. (That said, sometimes an already-good explanation can be improved by, say, adding an analogy.)
- We shouldn't have to send "signals" implicitly to communicate about question closure.

  - If someone else dupe-hammered a question *recently*, and you also have a hammer, **please don't reopen without some comment discussion** (which of course might be migrated to chat). If there are proposals to reopen from non-hammer-wielders, use the comments for that as well (perhaps preemptively).
  - If you want to tell OP to do more research, then **do that explicitly in the comments**. This way also provides an opportunity to, for example, demonstrate a specific web search query that would find the necessary results, or explain what jargon is needed to do the research properly.
  - Everyone knows (i.e., all the self-styled curators know) that Stack Overflow is a mess and that there are way too many unclosed questions. Pointing at a *specific* mess is better done by using a tag-specific chat room such as https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python - or better yet, a cleanup-effort-specific chat room such as https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion (my own); or by opening a discussion on Meta (if you don't mind that it might take a long time for SMEs to find it).
- The best way to create connectivity between questions that are the same, is for **all of them to point to a canonical**. The reason for connecting questions together is so that answers can be centralized and the best information is also the easiest to find.

At best, quintuple-hammering something is **starting** the process of cleaning up. The next steps:

- From what has been linked (or was considered for linking), figure out which is best.
- Clean up that version as much as possible.
- **Link everything else to that**:

  - the other candidates
  - the question that originally prompted the effort
  - duplicates of those other candidates - to find these, I use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1627844/1985162/duplicates-of-duplicates-of-a-canonical) (which I wrote) as a search aid
  - possibly other duplicates found with the site search and with an external search engine
- Save the question for future reference. When hammering future duplicates, use `in:saves` to improve search results.
- If you happen to have answered one or more of those questions, consider migrating your content to the canonical.

Sometimes, it will happen that there is an even better canonical out there, perhaps even one that other regulars know about. It's always possible to *iterate the process*: edit the better version if there's anything worth editing, and re-link everything from the previous-best to the newly-identified canonical.

### When the duplicates represent "pieces of the puzzle"

If solving OP's problem is straightforwardly a matter of following steps, and each one is addressed by a canonical (this actually happens a **lot**) then of course the question "needs more focus"; but hammer-wielders can close the question more expeditiously by closing with a duplicate of each. This has some advantages:

- OP gets an answer;
- FGITW gets prevented;
- This leaves behind *metadata* indicating that someone had both problems in conjunction. If it turns out that questions *keep* being closed with *the same* combination of otherwise unrelated duplicates, that becomes a *pattern* that can be noticed, and cleaned up later.

My recommendation when closing in this manner:

- save the question, in case such a pattern emerges.
- If the pattern does emerge, establish (or create) a canonical that addresses the problem, along the lines of:

  ```
  Q. How do I do Z?

  A. Though it might not be obvious, the Z task is a straightforward combination of [X](canonical link for 'how do I do X?') and [Y](canonical link for 'how do I do Y?'). Simply combine these techniques as follows:

  <full example, showing techniques from the best answers on the canonicals>
  ```

  Then, go back to the saved questions, and re-link them to the new canonical **instead of** to the individual step canonicals. If this canonical was written from scratch, consider making the answer community wiki; this should encourage others to improve that answer and discourage them from writing competing answers. (Unless, of course, it turns out that there is a reasonable way to do Z **other than** combining X and Y. In particular, if X and Y are library functionality, the Z functionality might get directly added in a later version.)
- If a pattern **doesn't** emerge, go back to the saved questions and vote to delete them. Generally, the pattern would only emerge because the combined task commonly needs a solution **and** because the combination of steps is non-obvious (such that a step-combining canonical has value).

This is, of course, asking for a **lot** of volunteer work; but I think this is the most streamlined workflow for it, that will get the best results.

Answer (score -11):

Given the following situation

- There are two questions A and B, which are mutual duplicates
- A was asked before question B.
- Both are unanswered.
- You answered question A, choosing correctly because A was asked first.
- You do not have the privilege to set question B as duplicate of A.

Then I came along to answer question B and then set question A as duplicate of question B.

In such a case I would have acted unethically. This community needs to realize that recognition and path to recognition is a badge of honor and motivation.

However, I would mark A as duplicate of B under the following circumstances even if A was asked first

- The language and explanation in question B were clearer and more comprehensive. I abhor bad or incomprehensible language.
- There were already five answers in B whereas A had only one answer, yours.

OTOH, the following must be the better answer:
[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question#:~:text=Merged%20question%20%2F%20merge%20stub%201%20A%20notice,target%20question%20for%20anonymous%20%28logged-out%29%20users.%20More%20items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question#:%7E:text=Merged%20question%20%2F%20merge%20stub%201%20A%20notice,target%20question%20for%20anonymous%20%28logged-out%29%20users.%20More%20items)

Comment: the age of the questions are somewhat irrelevant when it comes to which question should be the dupe target

Comment: That is like saying if two Olympic swimmers both have two gold and two silver medals, their ranking should not depend on their bronze medals.

Comment: In this case, the winner is the Q/A that does the best job at providing information, not the users who posted it.

Comment: ??? ~~~~ ???  It's not a contest. to win anything. It's a site to help people effectively and provide fulfilment to those who participate. If you want to win might as well use chatgpt.

Comment: Surely, they are continuing the Olympics metaphor as a shorthand for which question should be selected as the canonical dupe target.